# After importing existing gradle project while setting the Run configuration the project dropdown is showing as disabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

After importing existing gradle project while setting the Run configuration the project dropdown is showing as disabled .Also the imported project in not showing in package structure.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOF7D.png)

Comment: I feel you are selecting wrong project it should be discoverymind> discoverymind

check which is actual java project and point to that

Comment: i tried woth discoverymind>discoverymind its not working .I found the same is working with mac OS the problem is with windows only .Suspecting any issue with gradle file or not .But not sure